# (pure) Lucene: Counting documents having a timestamp in longfield, grouped by year

Tags: lucene, range, facet, faceted-search

My documents structure is:
[text:TextField,date:LongField]

I am looking for a 'statistic' query on my documents, based on a precision level on the dateTime field. This means counting documents grouped by the LongField date, ignoring some bytes at the right of the date.

For a given precision, I am looking for how many documents match for each different values of this precision.

Assuming the precision 'year' is grouping by "date/10000"
With the following data:

```
{text:"text1",dateTime:(some timestamp where year is 2015 like 20150000)}
{text:"text2",dateTime:(some timestamp where year is 2010 like 20109878)} 
{text:"text3",dateTime:(some timestamp where year is 2015 like 20150024)} 
{text:"text14,dateTime:(some timestamp where year is 1997 like 19970987)}
```

The result should be:

```
[{bracket:1997, count:1}
{bracket:2010, count:1}
{bracket:2015, count:2}]
```

While NumericRangeQuery allow to create 1 (or some) range, is it possible for lucene to generate the ranges based on a precision step?

I can handle this by creating a new field for each precision level that I need, but maybe this kind of things allready exists.

It's a kind of faceted search where the facet is the time. The use case should be:

```
-give me document count for each milleniums,
-then give me document count for each centuries (inside a millenium)
-then give me document count for each year (inside a century)
-then give me document count for each days (inside a year)
```

when 0 documents exists inside a bucket, the result should not be in the results.

Regards

Comment: give us some sample queries that you want to run, your query statement is abstract. if you want docs this year then do range query for this year and get how many of them, if you do by month, do again range query for months. Give more details where range query is not enough for u

Answer (score 0):

Collector can do this without any trick, here is the working code:

```
    public class GroupByTest1 {
    private RAMDirectory directory;
    private IndexSearcher searcher;
    private IndexReader reader;
    private Analyzer analyzer;

    private class Data {
        String text;
        Long dateTime;

        private Data(String text, Long dateTime) {
            this.text = text;
            this.dateTime = dateTime;
        }
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        directory = new RAMDirectory();

        analyzer = new WhitespaceAnalyzer();
        IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(directory, new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer));
        Data datas[] = {
                new Data("A", 2012L),
                new Data("B", 2012L),
                new Data("C", 2012L),
                new Data("D", 2013L),
        };

        Document doc = new Document();
        for (Data data : datas) {
            doc.clear();
            doc.add(new TextField("text", data.text, Field.Store.YES));
            doc.add(new LongField("dateTime", data.dateTime, Field.Store.YES));
            writer.addDocument(doc);
        }
        writer.close();

        reader = DirectoryReader.open(directory);
        searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
    }


    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        final Map<Integer, Long> map = new HashMap<>();
        Collector collector = new SimpleCollector() {
            int base = 0;

            @Override
            public void collect(int doc) throws IOException {
                String year = reader.document(doc + base).get("dateTime");
                if (!map.containsKey(Integer.valueOf(year))) {
                    map.put(Integer.valueOf(year), 1L);
                } else {
                    long l = map.get(Integer.valueOf(year));
                    map.put(Integer.valueOf(year), ++l);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean needsScores() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            protected void doSetNextReader(LeafReaderContext context) throws IOException {
                base = context.docBase;
            }
        };
        searcher.search(new MatchAllDocsQuery(), collector);
        for (Integer integer : map.keySet()) {
            System.out.print("year = " + integer);
            System.out.println(" count = " + map.get(integer));
        }
    }
}
```

Output I get is following:

```
year = 2012 count = 3
year = 2013 count = 1
```

This may run slow depending on how many records you have. It loads every single document to know what is the year on it and groups based on that. There is also grouping module which you may also look into it.

Comment: I edited my post to clarify my request. In fact I must not specify dates values, but return all existing differents dates values, at a specific precision level, with the number of documents inside each bucket. Regards.

Comment: Your example do the trick for one specific date (2012). Assume you  don't know the content of the database and you need to count documents for each distinct year that are inside the dateTime field. Thanks

Comment: it also shows you how to get for specific month(2013 february in the sample) and you can keep narrowing it.

Comment: It don't want to use a specific date. I need to the generate following statistics => count docs for each distinct year that are inside the dateTime fields values

Comment: You can use date like this: 20150101 means beginning of the year and 20151231 means end of year.  So range query for 20150101 - 20151231 would give all docs for 2015.

Comment: ok thanks for that but it's not what I need. I don't know what years exist in the database (and there is millions) I just want lucene to return me an array with all the years with the count.

Comment: Thank for your effort. Yes, there is billions of records... If no built-in solution exists, I will create one field by precision step I need, and simply group by them. It's not perfect since it become mandatory to know every precision step before the data is build.